# Shell script query to get report in tsv

Tags: mysql, linux, database, bash, shell

I am trying to execute a shell script to generate a `tsv` record. But the report is being generated with `\t` in the report instead of tabbed space. The command is working fine and generating tabbed space report when I run it through terminal.

```
 Query vsql -dxxxxx -Uxxxxxx -wxxxxxxx -F $'\t' -A -o samfile.tsv  -c 
 "select * from test.test;"
```

report though command line

```
test1   data1   format1  
test2   data2  format2
```

report though script

```
test1\tdata1\tformat1   
test2\tdata2\tformat2
```

How to resolve the `\t` issue within the script

Comment: Can you share the relevant portion of your bash script where you do this?

Comment: When you are on the CLI and issue this command, are you in a bash shell, or are you using some other shell? When you execute the script, are you executing like `bash script_name.sh`? Do you have a shebang at the top of your script: `#!/bin/bash` so it knows which shell to execute it in? That $'/t' is interpreted by bash to return a horizontal tab, so it seems like something is off on the script execution.

Comment: Thank you,earlier I was using shell,now the issue got resolved as you suggested by using shebang  bash and adding \ before $ as escape character.